# Misleading wrong answer in a popular question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answers

There is a popular question about inputting Unicode characters:
[How do you type Unicode characters using hexadecimal codes?](https://superuser.com/q/13086/456981)

And an *accepted* answer:
https://superuser.com/a/90669/456981

The problem is that the solution provided in the accepted and highly upvoted answer simply does not work. To be more specific, the answer suggests inputing character using Alt + decimal code (on numpad), which 
works only in rare case, namely it works for ANSI (ddd = 0-255) 
characters, or, if the number is preceded by zero, like 0dddd, it inputs "dddd modulo 256"-th character 
from selected codepage. Which obviously does not solve the general problem of inputting unicode characters by its ordinal (which was the question about).

The only Windows app (I tested on windows 10) where the solution worked for me was Word - it worked there as described. Everywhere else it did not work, and despite I am highly experienced user it took significant time to resolve the confusion caused by the answer.
I imagine for people with less experience it is extremely misleading, 
and many people are searching this problem to input e.g. some math symbols, etc.

So the only way that the answer would make sense - it should state in the first line put in bold, where and how exactly the solution may work.
Comments under the question note these problems, but the answer itself has not changed and stays highly misleading.

What should be made about it?
And what is usually made in such situations?

I could try edit the answer, but I can't test all the cases (Os versions/ apps) to give concrete answer, and I don't know what worked for them (maybe it worked somewhere, but it is not stated in the answer).

Comment: If you are using anything newer than Windows 7 that is the reason the accepted answer does not work.  In fact, neither answer will work, because the Unicode characters are entirely based on the font being used by the system and/or application (the font must be based on a Unicode font for it to work).

Comment: @Ramhound so was also my impression that it works on Win 7 only more or less globally, but I can't check it. At least this info should be well seen. Otherwise every time one reads this answer they will start pounding the numpad without success.

Comment: The only reason I know the Unicode codes behave differently on Windows 10 vs Windows 7 is because of a previous question about them.  I only read the question, due to a question, that was asked here.

Answer (score 2):

Not much to do really - we can't change the selected answer and I suspect editing it would be confusing.

While the ideal is one answer that works for all situations that's not always the case. I'd suggest simply upvoting the answers that worked for you.

I'd note the alt input method's pretty standard so... if it it doesn't work, its as much the app's problem as anything else

Comment: Upvoting relevant comments on the misleading answer is also helpful.